# IE7 li not in the same row

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, html-lists, inline

I'm creating a menu for a site and the menu is made of li's. In Chrome and Firefox everything works perfectly, but in IE7 the li's are in the same row, but stacked up in each other.

I did some research and tried these solutions:

- Adding a "Float" property
- Adding a "Width" property
- Adding a "Zoom" property set to 1
- Adding "white-space: nowrap" to the ul

And maybe some more that I don't remember. Non of them worked.

This is my code:

```css
#menu li {
  width: 150px;
  height: 44px;
  background: url('menu.png') repeat-x;
  display: -moz-inline-stack;
  display: inline-block;
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
  margin-left: -3px;
  border-left: 1px solid silver;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">1</a>
      <ul id="submenu">
        <li>a</li>
        <li>b</li>
        <li>c</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you've found the answer by yourself, please respond to this question with that answer.

Comment: ie7 might be tripping up on the ` *display:inline;`, preceding a style with a * within a style might cause the rest of the styling to fall apart

Comment: try position:relative;

Answer (score 0):

Since the question got voted for by others I am answering it without a hack and have it also crossbrowser compatible.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<style>
    #menu{
        float:right;
    }
    #menu li {
        width: 150px;
        height: 44px;
        border-left: 1px solid silver;
        float: left;
    }
    #submenu {
        margin:0;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">1</a>
        <ul id="submenu">
            <li>a</li>
            <li>b</li>
            <li>c</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
</ul>
```